# Cannot view MP4s in CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, mp4, redhat

I have a few files in MP4 format however I cannot see them in CentOS. They work fine in every other System. I can hear the audio but cannot see the video.

I have tried installing and uninstalling a few codecs as well as vlc but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Viewing issues are usually down to Codec issues - you can inspect the file using the Unix file command e.g.

```
> file GOPR0006.MP4
GOPR0006.MP4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, 3GPP JVT AVC
```

This should help you see what Codecs are required.  Mp4 is a container - so it can transport different codecs e.g. the file above includes data that is encoded using 3GPP.

Then it is a question of tracking down repositories to add them.

CentOS by its nature is quite a conservative distro - so if you are after the latest Codecs / media support then Fedora or Ubuntu may be better options.

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for the info, this is the result I get after the file command: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2. Do you know of a repository that would work on centos? thanks. John

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this seems to be related to the accelerated video output option. Just un-tick the box in the vlc preference tab and it will work as highlighted here:

https://superuser.com/questions/597581/vlc-on-centos-6-always-shows-black-screen